# Not showing a and b for subfigures

Tags: floats

I know there was a previous post about this but no matter the changes I make as shown in various posts, I can not get the caption to show a or b like it is suppose to. Instead I get Figure 1.1, Figure 1.2 and then the end caption is Figure 1.3. I want the subfigures labeled a and b and then have the overall figure labeled 1.1. (Note I looked at the previous post and modified it to look like it and it still did not work. I have the packages. Any advice would be great!

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image1.pdf}
      \caption[Image 1]{Image 1}
      \label{fig:I1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image2.pdf}
      \caption[Image 2]{Image2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Images]{Images}
  \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You should link to "previous post" and "various posts".

Comment: At least please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt, phd, onehalfspacing]{ncsuthesis}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text
\usepackage{subfig}    % composite figures
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[options]{natbib}

I go back and forth trying subcaption and subfigure as suggested by many others... still not working closest thing to work is Thanos response... but still does not work perfectly

Answer (score 4):

You missed the `width` for `subfigure` which is the mandatory argument:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
```

Use any length instead of `0.45\textwidth` as you need. Also don't leave blank lines in between two `subfigure`s as it will amount to a par break. With this I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %% no demo in your file
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image1.pdf}
      \caption[Image 1]{Image 1}
      \label{fig:I1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill                              %% no blank line here.
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image2.pdf}
      \caption[Image 2]{Image2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Images]{Images}
  \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately still does not work. Still shows 1.3 and 1.4 instead of a and b.

Comment: @pibsquared "does not work" is not enough information. Did you run my code as such? Is it working? Give a MWE.

Comment: If I only use package subcaption it will not compile. If I use both subfig and subcaption it will compile but it will label Image 1 as Figure 1 and Image 2 Figure 2 and Images as Figure 3. Instead of A and B for Image 1 and 2 respectively. I have exactly what you have above except had to add the subfig package to make it compile. If I try it with subfigure instead of subfig it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[Title Image 1]{\label{fig:I1}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image1.pdf}}\qquad
  \subfigure[Title Image 2]{\label{fig:I2}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Chapter-1/figs/Image2.pdf}}
\caption{Title of the whole image}
\label{fig:I}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is deprecated/obsolete  (and not supported anymore). Suggestions are to use [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Comment: This started to work but when I substituted the label with the labels I have made, it would not work anymore. It also shows the label next to the caption. SO it would be fig:I1 (a) Title Image 1. Not sure why.

Comment: @pibsquared : Would you mind posting your code to see what might be wrong?

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem I had both
\usepackage{subfig}
and 
\usepackage{subfigure}

It prefers subfigure

Comment: @pibsquared : Glad you could work it out!!!